# Foreign key doesn't work on the result of POST but GET works

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a problem working with foreign keys in Spring. The returned object doesn't have the correct value on my relation ship.

The `orderTypeId` of an `Order` is missing when in the CREATED response but a subsequent GET request yields the expected result.

### Expected behavior

Here's a small example of what I want to achieve.

**Request**

```
POST /api/orders
{
    "orderType": "orderTypes/1",
}
```

or `GET /api/orders/2`

**Output**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "orderTypeId": 1,            // either this
    "orderType": "orderTypes/1"  // or this
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/api/orders/2"
        },
        "order": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/api/orders/2"
        },
        "orderType": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/api/orders/2/orderType"
        },
        "orderType": {
            "href": "orderTypes/1" // this could even be acceptable
        }
    }
}
```

### My code

**Entites**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Order {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "order_type_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Long orderTypeId;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_type_id")
  private OrderType orderType;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class OrderType {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderType")
  private List<Order> orders;
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {}
```

**POST**

```
POST /api/orders
{
    "orderType": "orderTypes/1",
}
```

**Output**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "orderTypeId": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/api/orders/2"
        },
        "order": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/api/orders/2"
        },
        "orderType": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/api/orders/2/orderType"
        }
    }
}
```

However if I do `GET /orders/2` orderTypeId is correctly set.

What am I doing wrong?

---

### UPDATE

I tried something else

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Order {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn
  @JsonManagedReference
  @RestResource(exported=false) // ADDED
  private OrderType orderType;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class OrderType {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  // removed orders
}
```

**GET /api/orders/2**

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "orderTypeId": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "foo"
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/api/orders/2"
        },
        "order": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8090/api/orders/2"
        }
    }
}
```

But now POST doesn't work :(

```
POST /api/orders
{
    "orderType": "orderTypes/1",
}
```

Returns 400 Bad Request...

Comment: remove JsonIgnore and take a look to JsonManagedReference and JsonBackReference annotations. Usually entities are not return in REST APIs. Use DTOs

Answer (score 1):

Using `@JsonIgnore` is not the recommended way, to manage cyclic dependency please use `@JsonManagedReference` in your entities.
**Entities:**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

   @Column(name = "order_type_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private Long orderTypeId;

   @JsonBackReference(value="name")
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "order_type_id")
   private OrderType orderType;
}


@Data
@Entity
public class OrderType {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String name;

   @JsonManagedReference(value = "name")
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "orderType")
   private List<Order> orders;
}
```

Now to answer your question, the return of post API will not return OrderType as Hibernate does not recognise it as an initialised entity.
You can either do a GET call later as happening in your case already or have a rest controller in a POST api after saving you can do a get call by id before returning or use a DTO for sending response.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the `@JsonIgnore` issue. I changed that. So now I have to setup DTOs for my `@RepositoryRestResource` do you have any good resources on that? I'd like to avoid having to implement the controllers manually and keep using the "easy out of the box" solution

Comment: Thanks for `@JoinColumn(name = "order_type_id")` it helped me a lot. I wanted fk_id to be included in my response for Order Table and tried so many things as I am very new to Spring.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this field will not be populated when a new instance is constructed i.e. as a result of a POST request. It will however be populated in response to a GET request i.e. it will be populated by Hibernate as a result of the JPA annotations on the field.

I am not quite sure why you would need to map this as a persistent field. Simply adding a getter should mean it is included in any JSON response:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Order {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "order_type_id")
  private OrderType orderType;

  public Long getOrderTypeId(){
    return orderType != null ? orderType.getId() : null;
  }
}
```

Failing that you could add a listener for an `AfterCreateEvent`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

and either set the value manually on this listener based on the associated `OrderType` or, inject an `EntityManager` to your listener and trigger a refresh on the saved instance:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh(java.lang.Object)

```
@RepositoryEventHandler 
public class OrderEventHandler {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

  @HandleAfterCreate
  public void onOrderCreated(Order o) {
    em.refresh(o);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just adding the method causes this error `Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [orderTypeId] on this ManagedType [com.demo.model.Order]`. I find it rather strange that it's so complicated to expose foreign keys or related resource links. For instance I assumed that when I created the OneToMany relation that a property would appear on the entity that looked a bit like `{ orderType: "orderTypes/1" }` because that info is already on the entity. Joining the actual entity into the result I can see some issues with

Comment: For instance I can do a `PATCH { orderType: "orderTypes/2" }` and it works. Why isn't the orderType field exposed when I GET the `order`. It puzzles me greatly

Comment: I assume you meant POST rather than GET in your last comment. Because PATCH will load the existing entity and merge the updated values. As a result of it being loaded from the database the field will be set due to the JPA annotations on it.

Comment: I did mean PATCH. It was to demonstrate that it knows of the property and uses the resource url format. So it should be doable to add it to the output without having to jump through hoops

Comment: I am confused: "Why isn't the orderType field exposed when I GET the order" you asked. I thought it was...

Comment: Sorry, I can see how it's confusing. And you're correct, I do want the orderType field exposed when I GET the order. The example with the PATCH was to show that the field is in there somewhere it's just not being included in the GET output